# Codeigniter: 3 Submit buttons, one function?

Tags: function, codeigniter, submit

I have a page with three forms.

I'd like to run different db calls corresponding to the button clicked.

I have a 2 lib functions.  One validates, and the passes it to the _submit function...

How can I separate the _submit function based on which submit button is clicked?
[alt text http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/171/screenshot20100119at245.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/171/screenshot20100119at245.png)

Comment: Why can't you just have three forms each with its own action and submit button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either set up 3 different forms, each with its own action, or you can set different values for each submit button and take action based on the value of the `submit` variable.

**View**

```
<form name="my_form" action="some/action/validate/">
    <input type="submit" value="paypal" name="submit" />
    <input type="submit" value="promo" name="submit" />
    <input type="submit" value="employee" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
function validate() {
    $my_action = $this->input->post('submit');
    if (my_action == 'paypal') {
        // Your logic
    }... etc
}
```

Comment: I'm a super-beginner.  Could you give an example of the action?

Comment: def validate()? Not a Pythonista by any chance are you? ;)

Comment: @John *Laughs* I am, and proud of it! I doubt the browsers care though ;-)  Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

if(my_action = "paypal") must be if(my_action **==** "paypal")

detail...